# This or that in paragraphs

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused about "this" and "that" usage. For example, what is better to use in this sentence and, most importantly, why. I can't understand which to choose in a particular case.

> Objective negative feedback is a gift to the company, a free audit that shows growth areas. **This/That** is how it should be treated and not as a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most basic of contexts, '*this*' is used for something you can show the person you are speaking to, either because you are holding it, it is close by, or you can take the person to it. By contrast, '*that*' is something slightly more distant, such as something you can point at. So, for example, if you were introducing someone to your friend by bringing them over you might say "*this is my friend*", but if you were pointing out your friend to someone across a crowded room you might say "*that is my friend, over there in the red shirt*".

In written language, the distinction is similar. If you introduce an example of something, or give an explanation or reason for something, you may then refer back to it using 'this' or 'that'. As a general rule, we use 'this' if we are continuing to discuss the thing and the subject is still 'present', and 'that' if we have concluded and the subject is in the past.

Your example seems to require 'that', because you've made a simple statement that objective treatment is "a gift", but then gone on to say something else, so that thought (at least the specific metaphor of a 'gift') isn't being continued.